# Counting in R Using the Which Statement

Tags: r

I am trying to count the number of times text is in a column and using the which clause. So if I need to count all the "yes" in column A where column B has "France"

```
    xx <- length(grep(da[which(da$fruit == "yes" & da$Q1 == "France")]))

    Error in grep(da[which(da$fruit == "yes" & da$Q1 == "France")]) : 
    argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `xx <- length(which(da$fruit=='yes' & da$Q1=='France'))`

Comment: Why do you use `grep`? Something like `length(which(da$fruit == "yes" & da$Q1 == "France"))` should work

Comment: `sum((da$fruit == "yes") & (da$Q1 == "France"))`

Comment: @Starbucks Do you have `NA` values? Then `sum((da$fruit == "yes") & (da$Q1 == "France"), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: @jogo Comparison between characters and factors just works since the factor is coerced to character during the comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your which statement doesn't need `grep`

```
xx <- length(which(da$fruit=="yes" & da$Q1=="France"))
```

---

ex.)

`> da`

```
fruit      Q1
-----------------
  no       France
  no       Spain
  yes      Spain
  yes      USA
  no       France
  yes      France
  no       USA
  yes      France
```

---

`which(da$fruit=="yes" & da$Q1=="France")`

Returns:

```
> [1]  6  8
```

---

`length(which(da$fruit=="yes" & da$Q1=="France"))`

Returns:

```
> [1] 2
```

---

**which():** https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/which.html

> Gives the TRUE indices of the object you are searching for.

**length():** https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/length.html

> Will give you the length of the vector of the TRUE indices. Therefore returns the count of the items that fit the criteria you provided.